# How to run a particular code only during the installation of the app?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on SQLite and i want that a particular code should only be executed while the app is being installed . I have read that this can be achieved using Shared preference but i'm unable to understand how it works. Can somebody please explain..

I want to copy messages from sms/inbox to my app's database which should happen only once during installation and only the new arrived messages should be added to the database after that.

Comment: `a particular code should only be executed while the app is being installed` **which** code? copying the database from the `assets` folder? You don't need to do that at installation time.

Comment: You cannot run any code at installation time. At most, you can run code that detects the first time your app has been run since it was installed (or since the user cleared your app's data).

Comment: I want to copy messages from sms/inbox to my app's database which should happen only  once during installation and only the new arrived messages should be added to the database after that. @Rotwang

Comment: `which should happen only once during installation`. You were already told that that is impossible during installation. So why repeat this impossible wish?

Comment: you cannot run code during instalation. Maybe you would want to do this at the first run of the app after installation.

Comment: @IspasClaudiu how to run the code only during the 1st run ??

Comment: @greenapps i really really really need a solution for my problem ....

Comment: Use Shared Preferences to read and store a key "firstrundone" or "codeexecuted". If false then run the code and set on true when done.

Comment: @vinuthna alla You should reconsider your question than.

Comment: ya sure..@IspasClaudiu

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared Preferences to read and store a key "firstrundone" or "codeexecuted". If false then run the code and set on true when done.